# When running SQL 2019 Ent on Windows 2019 Datacenter in Google Compute Engine (GCE), cannot connect SSMS to local db. Error 18456

Tags: sql-server, google-compute-engine

I successfully launched an sql 2019 enterprise on windows 2019 dc in google compute engine.  According to Google documentation on [Managing SQL Server Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/sql-server/creating-sql-server-instances#manage_sql) - it uses Windows Authentication to manage the instance.  I am using RDP directly to the database server and attempting to login with SSMS with the local windows credentials that were created by GCE.  I have verified these are local administrator credentials.

The first error I received was about named pipes, so I enabled named pipes in the SQL Configuration and restarted the SQL Server Service.  That did resolve that specific issue.

My new connection error, according to Windows Application Log:

- Log Name: Application
- Source: MSSQLSERVER
- Event ID: 18456
- User: xx\xxxxx
- Task Category: Logon
- Keywords: Classic,Audit Failure
- Computer: xx
- Message: Login failed for user 'xx\xxxx'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Login lacks Connect SQL permission. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

I reviewed this [very helpful article at sqlauthority about error 18456](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/19/sql-server-login-failed-for-user-reason-token-based-server-access-validation-failed-with-an-infrastructure-error/) and what it entails.  However, when looking at how to resolve this issue for a local windows user account, I'm at a loss.  I do not know how to grant this permission to a local windows user without logging into the system via SSMS, which is the product I'm trying to use to connect to the local database.  I've also verified there are no additional users on the system.  Can someone please assist?

How can I run
`GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [DOMAIN\User]`
Without SSMS software?  Anyone else have experience with this issue?

Comment: Using SSMS you shouldn't need to type in a username and password for Windows Auth. Just select Windows Authentication in the login box and click Connect. If you are typing in username and password then you are using SQL Authentication or Azure Authentication, which is wrong. Just to verify: you are trying to connect while logged in locally to the machine? Or you are logged in to a client machine and trying to connect remotely

Comment: Find the ERRORLOG file on disk, look for the 18456 error messages and check the state code against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error). If the state number is 6 it means that you're attempting to use SQL Login authentication (username and password) for Windows accounts.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for clarifying, yes.  I am not entering a user/pass into the SSMS platform.  It's attemptign to use the locally logged on windows user in the platform.  I think this is specific to GCE - I've installed and used SSMS on other SQL platforms.  As I stated in the post, I am remote controlling the server that SQL/SSMS are both installed on - so the logon is all local, no client machine.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you for the guidance.  I found ERRORLOG in the <installpath>\MSSQL\Log folder.  It's noting details from the startup about 8am this morning, then says nothing after that.  I've restarted the SQL Server service, and the file updated with ERRORLOG.1 filename and entries in it for the shut down, but no further detail.  Is there a Startup Parameter I should set on the MS SQL Server instance in Server Configurator in order to get it to write EventID 18456 details into the ERRORLOG file?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I was able to get more information directly from the SSMS client than I was finding in the Application event log.  nder additional data, it's Error Number: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 1, Line Number: 65536 - the response for state 1 on the page you linked is "Error information is not available. This state usually means you do not have permission to receive the error details. Contact your SQL Server administrator for more information." - bad news for me, it's asking me to contact me.

Comment: You need to configure [Login Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/configure-login-auditing-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15) to be able to see the details in the log files. But for that you will need to be able to login to SSMS, which you can't do. But it looks like the message you have above *"Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Login lacks Connect SQL permission"* should be enough: check if your user is Administrator on the machine. SQL Server gives local administrators `superadmin` rights by default

Comment: If you are admin and still locked out then see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you!  Yes, the account is a local administrator to the server.  I will review the Microsoft doc, that seems very helpful.  If that fails, I'll just have to engage Google Support for this project - which is only lasting a couple more months so it shouldn't break the budget.

Comment: @Charlieface the documentation on granting admin access in single user mode using SQLCMD did the trick for me.  I suspect the GCE scripting just didn't account for the scenario in which I created the admin user after the image loaded SQL enterprise.  In any event, please post this as an answer to the question so I can upvote/award you.

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/how-do-you-reset-the-sa-password/49767#49767

Comment: This comment is about the question being closed:  None of those indicated to me what the issue was.  None of the troubleshooting I did, nor the error messages that came up in my search led me to those solutions.  This wasn't a case of "had access, now I don't what's up" this was a case of "never had access before in GCE, why is it like this, what is the issue" - I don't know how to express that even though the solution was similar, the use case is different.  But stackoverflow needs to manage the community in it's own way I guess.